# How to wait in javascript for the page to be loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am currently developing a Chrome extension that automatically submits a form to the server. I know that there is a function on the page that will allow me to submit the form. I tested using the Chrome console and made sure that it works, but a problem occurred.  The Javascript function gets executed before being defined, resulting in an `UnknownReferenceError`, and the form can't be submitted.

I tried using jQuery's `on("load")` and `setTimeout` functions, but neither worked properly. jQuery won't log the message.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  setTimeout(submit()),10000);
  console.log("submitted the form successfully");
})
```

Comment: the first argument to setTimeout is a function, not the result of calling a function ... `submit()` calls the function immediately - therefore the the submit code runs immediately, usually resulting in a new page being loaded (the result of submitting a form)

Comment: I think you can pick the root element and check if it has been loaded then call the necessary function like this..
`document.getElementById("idOfRootElement").onload = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  // Do something
}` 
It might work.

Comment: To access JavaScript functions defined by the page you need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704). Also you don't need jQuery for this, you can simply do window.addEventListener('load', () => { ... }) however it may be unnecessary so try without it first.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm You answered mine question!

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function () { alert("Page is loaded.") }
```